# CSS Button :focus pseudo class

Tags: html, css, button, pseudo-class

How Would I make it so that when I click a button, the button stays that color until another button is clicked?

To clarify, imagine you have a text box. When you click it, you can add a border because you have it like `input:focus{border:#000}` and when the input loses focus or another text box is clicked, the border properties go back to the default.

How would I accomplish this with a button. I feel like I'd need to use :after or something.

#### My Code

```
button.top_bar {
    background-color:#E3E3E3;
    border:#DCDCDC 1px solid;
    border-radius:3px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    postion:relative;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    top:5;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left:15px;
}

button.top_bar:hover {
   border:#9F9F9F 1px solid;
}

button.top_bar:focus {
    border:#9F9F9F 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking... Your code seems to work fine. `button:focus` is totally legit, it even works in even IE6. What's not working here?: http://jsfiddle.net/V3FKw/

Comment: Haha its worded odd. I want that border to stay after the button is clicked and the mouse moved away.

Comment: That's already what happens though, the style is applied until the element loses **focus**. Ways to lose focus include clicking somewhere else or tabbing into the next element that can receive focus, but not mouse movement. Explain what's not working for you.

Comment: But notice how that isn't the case. You click on it, and nothing happens. Take the mouse off the button and no border. The border needs to not go away.

Comment: Its like a link when, you have the class `:active`, so you can change the color of the link when its clicked, until something else is clicked.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? it works just fine for me... Aha, except in Chrome. Lol, Googling it came up with this (not helpful, something I myself answered a long time ago): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832436/css-focus-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome Check other browsers though, it does work as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike text inputs, some browsers don't seem to grant focus when button elements are clicked. Add to your button element an attribute onclick="this.focus()" to force the issue. No jQuery needed :-)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of doing this is with jQuery, or some sort of Javascript. Here's how I would do it: I would control it via a class (let's call it ".selectedBorder"). Then on click, grab all your buttons that you have, and turn off the borders for all of them, then just add it on the clicked one. Here's an example:

```
//first you grab the click event for the button(s)
$("#buttons").click(function(){

    //we remove all the borders from all the buttons
    $("#buttons").removeClass("selectedBorder");

    //Now we add the border to the button that's been clicked
    $(this).addClass("selectedBorder");

});
```

That should do the trick. Just add that in a javascript tag or an external file and include it, and you should be good to go. Hope that helps.