# How to show/hide content on click with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, onclick, show-hide

I have put together this simple code for showing/hiding some content on click using CSS only. It works as I want it to in FF but wont work in Chrome or Safari (untested as yet in IE)

http://jsfiddle.net/fW3yW/

Can someone please tell me why it wont work in these browsers and suggest an alternative (using CSS only if possible)?

Here is the site where the code is being used - http://www.themontessoripeople.co.uk/montesori/?page_id=20#policies-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added tabindex, works in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/fW3yW/1/

From here: [css focus not working in safari and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832436/css-focus-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome)

jQuery method: http://jsfiddle.net/fW3yW/12/

Comment: Thanks, that worked great.

Have you any idea how I could stop the drop-down link taking the user to the top of the page onclick without breaking the function.

Maybe an alternative to # in the href?

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0);"` But I agree with the other people here that a jQuery solution would probably be better. I'm honestly surprised this even works.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I've added the JS too. Ben.

Answer (score 2):

You're abusing CSS. The `:focus` psuedo-class is meant for styling form elements that have focus, rather than for `<a>` links, where browsers might implement `:focus` differently, and then there's also the similar `:active` psuedo-class.

I suggest you do not hide anything by default with CSS, but use jQuery to hide the elements on-load, then use jQuery to create show/hide animations (easily done with a single line of code) when a link is clicked. It's a lot more elegant and works on more browsers.

Comment: I'm aware this isn't what it's intended for. I'm just wary of using too much Java in a wordpress page, they aren't exactly streamline to begin with and my knowledge of Java isn't great. If you would kindly suggest a Java alternative that only uses a small amount of code then I'll try it out. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: jQuery and Javascript has nothing to do with Java except for the name.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a CSS3 selector, with an XHTML doctype. I don't know that all browsers will handle CSS3 with an XHTML doctype tag - though the two specs aren't necessarily tied together.

Have you tried changing the doctype to indicate HTML5? (Then, of course, that brings up all kinds of HTML5shim questions...)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery instead...way more reliable and elegant.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp