# Why default button overrides outline on focus event?

Tags: html, css

I do not know if it is a bug or not, but it seems to be.

When you have a default `button` and you click it when you have a [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo class it does not seem to have an `outline`.

```css
#buttontag:focus {
}
```

```html
<button id="buttontag" type="button">Focus me</button>
```

It shows the `outline` when you use <kbd>tab</kbd> key, though.

Nevertheless, it shows the `outline` both when clicking or using <kbd>tab</kbd> key on the `button` if you change the `background-color` to it.

```css
#buttontag:focus {
  background-color: #dde;
}
```

```html
<button id="buttontag" type="button">Focus me</button>
```

But it does not work for all types of `background-color`. For example, it does not work for `background-color: #ddd`. In this case it is only shows when you use <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

```css
#buttontag:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button id="buttontag" type="button">Focus me</button>
```

Here an screenshot when the `button` is focused, nothing changes.

[image]

I know that the `background-color: #ddd` is the same colour as the default border of the `button` (both on focus or not focused). I have created the following code to be sure of it.

```js
var buttontag = document.getElementById('buttontag');
buttontag.onfocus = function(){
  var border = window.getComputedStyle(buttontag).getPropertyValue("border");
  alert(border);
}

var border = window.getComputedStyle(buttontag).getPropertyValue("border");
alert(border);
```

```css
#buttontag:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button id="buttontag" type="button">Focus me</button>
```

I know that `rgb(221, 221, 221)` is the same as `#DDDDDD` on hex and that is the same as `#ddd`. I do not know if it has to be something related about contrast between both colours (there is no contrast because they are the same colour) and `outline` but it is very strange that in this `background-color` the `outline` does not appear.

**More and more strange**

If you inspect the default `button` and you force it to be focussed (I am trying on `Google Chrome` debugger) , it has an `outline` and shows it on the button. It is the default `outline` that appears in the rest of `buttons` with another `background-color`.

```
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

And I also wanted to know if it was something related about forcing the `button` to be in focus state so I created a `Javascript` snippet to see what `outline` the button has in `focus` state.

```js
var buttonFocus = document.getElementById('buttontag');

buttonFocus.onfocus = function(){
  var outline = window.getComputedStyle(buttonFocus).getPropertyValue("outline");
  alert(outline);
}
```

```css
#buttontag:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button id="buttontag" type="button">Focus me</button>
```

It retrieves the default `outline`, but does not show it. It seems that it only shows the `outline` if you force the `button` to be focussed (on the debugger).

I have searched on the official documentation but could not find anything related about a *special behaviour* for default `buttons` or specific `background-color`.

So here I have some questions:

- Why is the `outline` not displayed on the default `button` when you click on it?
- Why with `background: #ddd` it is not shown also?
- Why is the `outline` shown when you use <kbd>tab</kbd> and not when you click on the `button` (on the two cases above)?
- Why the `button` has the `outline` in his `CSS` but it does not display it? Is it a bug?

Comment: Note: on OSX it works with `background-color: #dde;` on click.

Comment: @Vucko Yes, as I pointed above, _it shows the outline both when clicking or using tab key on the button if you change the background-color to it._ Look at my second example, it shows the `outline` when you click on it. I am using `Windows 10` OS.

Comment: @Error404 if you could add some screenshots it would be awesome, thanks

Comment: Is this behavior specific to Chrome? I'm not seeing the same behavior on any other browser.

Comment: @BoltClock I only have tried on `Google Chrome`. Are you also getting the same result? Maybe it is only happening on Chrome.

Comment: @yev Yes, sure. What screenshots do you need?

Comment: @Error404 for example #3 (`#ddd` colored focused button)

Comment: @yev Screenshot added.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal That's true but then it does not have a lot of sense that in some cases when you click, the outline appears and in other cases it is hidden. Also, it is very strange that when you click on a button (as my  last example) it has the outline, but not display it.

Answer (score 2):

Might be wrong.

1. The default button (in Google Chrome at least) uses `appearance`
   style attribute:

   ```
   button {
       -webkit-appearance: button;
   }
   ```

   The `appearance` property allows you to make elements look like a
   **standard user interface element from your operating system**. Talking about OS X, standard interface buttons do not have outline
   by default.

   Very easy way to check how the standard os buttons looks:

   `alert('I am standard button')`

   When you've created a `button:focus` pseudo-class that contained
   `background` or `border` rule (example #2), you have overridden the
   standard appearance by **default browser style** for button + your
   rules.

   In example #1, the `button:focus` is empty, and apparently it is
   just ignored by the browser, hence os interface style is applied.

   If you will create a style:

   ```
   button { -webkit-appearance: initial; }
   ```

   you will get default browser button that has outline.
2. Chrome's default style for button has a rule:

   ```
   background-color: buttonface;
   ```

   Safari and Google Chrome support custom color names that are
   references to the currently used colors of user interface elements.
   It might be the case, that `buttonface` is `'#dddddd'` in your system. Interesting though, as I can see the blue outline in OS X Chrome. [image]

For the questions 3 and 4, I am afraid I cannot replicate it, as I do get outline.

Will update the answer after some research. Cheers! :)

Comment: I only could find this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) about `webkit-appearance` but it seems that you will not use it on production sites: _Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user._ so I do not know why it is being used here. Also, is your image from the example in which I am using `background: #ddd`? I can see in this case only the blue outline when I use tab key, but not when click on the button. I am using `Windows 10` and `Google Chrome`.

Comment: Yes, its from `#ddd` example. I do get it on mouse click tool. It easily can be a bug on windows chrome.

Comment: concerning `appearance`, it is set by default in browser. Basically my point was: browser will try to show buttons as they appear in operating system (which can not have outline), if no button styles defined.

Comment: @Error404: Chrome's UA stylesheet is not a "production site facing the Web"

Comment: @yev Yes, it would have sense for the example 1 but then it should appear when `background: #ddd` is displayed on the example 3.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, then I do not understand what they mean with that. Also, I do not exactly know what UA is (sorry if it is a beginner question).

Comment: @Error404: UA = user agent = browser. If you are a beginner, you would do well to ignore these properties. Just know that they are reserved for internal use and that, as advised, you should avoid using them in your own CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, I did not think about to use it. I am just curious and wanted to know a bit more about why this behaviour happens on the buttons. So, when they talk about _production sites facing the Web_ they refer to the own CSS?

Comment: @Error404 yes,  exactly

Answer (score 0):

`webkit` Chrome and Safari behave differently, in that they do not trigger `:focus` on a click event, but do on `tab` keyboard event.

That `:focus` behavior is present, especially on the `button` element.

So you might have to add `tabindex` attribute on your `button` element to let the browser know that this element can receive focus.

```
tabindex="0"
```

Since without that `tabindex` attribute, the browser sees that focus flag as being false, hence no `:focus`.

See W3C spec:

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act

> There may be document language or implementation specific limits on which elements can become :active or acquire :focus.

Also see the following regarding focused browsing context

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#currently-focused-area-of-a-top-level-browsing-context

> If the attribute is omitted or parsing the value returns an error.
>
> The user agent should follow platform conventions to determine if the element's tabindex focus flag is set and, if so, whether the element and any focusable areas that have the element as their DOM anchor can be reached using sequential focus navigation, and if so, what their relative position in the sequential focus navigation order is to be.
>
> Modulo platform conventions, it is suggested that for the following elements, the tabindex focus flag be set:
>
> - a elements that have an href attribute
> - link elements that have an href attribute
> - button elements

You can also see this related StackOverflow question:

[css focus not working in safari and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832436/css-focus-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome)

Comment: It seems also does not work neither with `tabindex` attribute. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2rwh48s/)

Comment: And it could have sense when I leave the `:focus` event without assign any property but I think it should work when I use `background-color: #ddd`.

Comment: The W3C spec does state that ` implementation specific limits on which elements can become :active or acquire :focus.` So i think it tries to cover its booty, leaving the `implementation` up to the browser. Which is their way of saying its buggy. :(

Answer (score 0):

button has a default style define by each browser. it might (and often is) different from browser to browser. But we can overwrite the default values to suit our needs.

#### Why is the outline not displayed on the default button when you click on it?

*The button doesn't enter in focus state when you click. It enters the active state.*

#### Why with background: #ddd it is not shown also?

*It does show in my browser, but only when in focus. I your examples you use #ddd and #dde which are 2 very similar grays to the default gray, but once I changed the value I could see the difference.*

#### Why is the outline shown when you use tab and not when you click on the button (on the two cases above)?

*The focus state is meant to allow the user to hit the Enter/Return key to activate the button. However, the button doesn't enter the focus state one it is clicked*

#### Why the button has the outline in his CSS but it does not display it? Is it a bug?

*It is not a bug. It only displays when in focus state, which can be forced through the code inspector, via javascript or by tabbing through form elements. I used my own example declaring:*
outline: 2px solid  #ccc;
The focus state is very useful when trying t make the application/website accessible to screen readers for people who are visually impaired. It allows us to add more functions that can be triggered in those situations, and to guide the user through the page when looking at it isn't possible.

Comment: But when I use `background-color: #dde` the blue outline is shown and never when I use `background-color: #ddd`. All of you refers that each style for the button depends on the browser. It is ok. But it also does not answer why some buttons shows the outline, and others not (for example, with a specific background). Further, I am looking for answers with links/references that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

The default browser behavior is to show an outline only on focus (by using tab f.e.), not on click. Each browser also may have it's default outline color and width. 
To avoid any funny behavior you can overwrite the outline, and also add it to a click:

```
#buttontag:focus, #buttontag:active {
  outline: #ddd solid 2px;
}
```

Comment: I know how to simulate the effect. I am not looking that. I am looking for links/references that demonstrates why it happens.

Comment: Ah okay. I thought to add it as I didn't see it mentioned yet. As it seems to be browser specific I guess it's hard to find any references on it... Think the best info can be found on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline with links to specs - but still that's nothing to do with the choices of browser vendors.... maybe contact them if you're eager to know? Good luck!