# CSS - :focus Not Working on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

When I click a link the font-size does not get bigger on iOS but on android it does work. How do I get it to work

**What I have tried:**

ontouchstart="" in the body tag

**jQuery:**

```
$(".primary-menu li a").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css("font-size", "15px");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.primary-menu li a:focus {
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

Neither the jQuery or CSS Works on the iOS only Android

Thank You

Comment: any help on this problem?

Comment: Try adding `tabIndex="0"` to your `.primary-menu` object. This has been already addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832436/css-focus-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem of non working `:focus` selector (in my case on a `button`) on iOS and this is my solution:

```
<button onclick="this.focus()">Button</button>
```

So it is necessary to manually `focus()` the button `onclick` (I have no clue why). In my case it seemed to be to only working solution, tried others here:
https://jsfiddle.net/sz1L75ro/8/

In case of the problem of the threadstarter I would suggest to also add the same `onclick` listener to the `a` elements:

```
<a onclick="this.focus()">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

By no means an expert on css, or JavaScript for that matter but Googling around the same subject area (pure css event actions for iOS/mobile) has shown me that examples are quite hard to come by, however where I was looking for examples with flyouts here is an interesting example:

- [https://codepen.io/Tont/pen/hdsev][1] - Using a checkbox with 'display: none' over a button. The css references whether this input is 'checked' here:

  input:checked ~ ul.submenu{
    max-height:300px;
    transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
  }

The same hidden checkbox methodology could be used to implement a pure css 'click' event handler with the action to be taken being change the font size of the `<a>` element.

Can't really help you with the JQuery as I don't have a way to test my code easily on iOS, however maybe try `.setAttribute(<attribute_name>, <attribute_value>)` instead of `.css`.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution seems to add a `tabindex="0"` attribute on the element. This way, CSS selector works.

Last problem is that focused element doesn't lose focus when you click outside of it.