# The Button :focus style is not working on phone?

Tags: html, css

The code:

**HTML**

```
<button type="radio"/>
```

**CSS**

```
button:focus {
    background: red;
}
```

When I click it in the mobile phone's browser, the style is not working.

Comment: Did you mean "<input type="radio" /> "or "<button> text </button>", as <button type="radio"/> dosen't exist

Comment: <button> text </button>

Comment: Could you please give some more details and images of the issue so we can try to better understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

The :focus pseudo class in CSS is used for styling an element that is currently targeted by the keyboard, or activated by the mouse. Here is an example

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/trp7ua1c/2/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <button class="btn" type="button" name="button">
    click
</button>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
  color: #000;
  background: red;
```

}

```
.btn:focus {
   background: green;
 }
```

Comment: Which mobie your using. its working for me click the button

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this solve your problem? [CSS - :focus Not Working on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128132/css-focus-not-working-on-ios)

```
<button onclick="this.focus()">Button</button>
```